# What Are the Algorithm and techniques of IP Traceback?

Tags: attacks, ddos, tracking

In most of the cases the cyber attacks such as a DDoS attack or other kinds, it is sometimes hard/impossible to identify the real source IP addresses. This is because when you review the logs and lookup those IP addresses you usually find that the addresses belong to victims.

When you report the crime to cyber-attack investigator agencies, how can they find real IP's or persons behind it?

Comment: Can I also point out, attempting to trace this kind of traffic is a fairly futile task. I find it interesting you point out how the FBI would do such a thing but you fail to acknowledge that they're a govt. funded agency with an incredible amount of power and resources, something which your company will never be able to match regardless of its size. What you're attempting to do, isn't worth the time it will take especially as there is a high chance you will end up no closer to the attacker from where you left off.

Comment: @R1- your example makes no sense. The IPs that participate in a DDoS are both the attackers and victims themselves. Those are the real IPs. If you want to know who runs the C&C server that coordinates the attacks, that's a completely different problem. The "algorithm" is to perform forensic analysis to work down the chain of linked machines..

Comment: @Joshua.J Claiming the FBI has an "incredible amount of power and resources" is the TV view of the government. In reality, at least when it comes to "cyber" crimes, they are incredibly naïve. All their "experts" are new recruits who are paid well below market value who are quickly scooped up by private companies as soon as they start to learn their shit. Whenever the FBI makes a bust, they're either incredibly lucky, or social engineer an incredibly stupid criminal. All they will do in this case is ask the ISP for some info and give up as soon as they realize it's a botnet.

Comment: @forest Maybe I should've been clearer, in terms of power I meant the ability to control and in terms of resources I meant money. Two things which they do have an incredible amount of, at least more than his company/him has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You, as an individual, can't find who's behind an IP address.

Well, you can grab an IP address via social-engineering tricks if you suspect someone, but if you have no idea who to suspect, then you're basically out of options here.

The FBI is a government agency, they can just ask your [Internet Service Provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) because the law may allow them to do so during an investigation.

Your ISP have your personal information, they'll communicate them to the FBI: it's that easy.

Comment: R1, obviously they do not have jurisdiction in every single country in the world, but you used them as an example and thus Benoit is too. The point is, the ISP has *some* of the information you require, thus you should leave this kind of witch hunt or whatever it may be to them.